# What is the type and memory binding of a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, binding

I am learning about variable attribute binding in C++, but there is a question I have not been able to find a good answer for on the web. Suppose I have the code:

```
char *pointer;
pointer = new char[100];
```

I know that the second line declares a nameless explicit heap-dynamic variable and allocates 100 bytes of memory for the array, but I am unsure of the type and memory binding for the first line of code. Intuition tells me it would be a stack-dynamic variable with a single byte allocated, but I am not completely sure. I am also not sure what the binding time of the type of the pointer is. If it were just a regular char, it would be at compile time, but does that hold for pointers?

Comment: I don't think C++ has a thing called variable attribute binding.

Comment: Yes, the pointer `char *pointer` here is allocated on the stack and occupies some memory (most likely 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system). Remember a pointer is just an address and an address is a number.

Comment: Variable `pointer` is an *automatic* variable (stack) large enough to hold the address in memory of a `char`.

Comment: @DeiDei why is the memory 4 bytes or 8 bytes? I thought 1 byte for the char data type was standard to C and C++

Comment: @djman If a pointer was of size 1 byte then you'd only be able to have 255 addresses available. That doesn't seem right, does it? The `T` in `T*` only matters when the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: @DeiDei oh, that makes sense. I was treating it as a regular char and not a pointer

Comment: To finish it up, a pointer is always the same size on a system. Also it always points to 1 byte in memory as a byte is the smallest addressable chunk of memory. When the pointer is dereferenced, its type specifies how many bytes to dereference, starting from the one it's pointing to plus `sizeof(type)`.